# What is the appropriate way to access data from Python sets?

Tags: python

If a set that always consists of *one* element (the element is an element of a custom class which contains different data types) is returned by a function, what is the appropriate way to access that element?

At the moment I just use a `for` loop to loop through the elements of the set, but since I know that the set will contain only one element there must be a better way to access the data.

So instead of this:

```
my_set = {'Custom type'}
for i in my_set:
    print(i)
```

What would be the best way to access the element contained in the set. (Please assume that the content of the actual set is a custom type and not a string like in the example given.)

Comment: If the function always returns a set of a single thing, why not modify the function so it returns the single thing instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use unpacking:

```
s = {'item'}  # 1-element set

item, = s   # unpacking (note the comma)
print(item)
```

Comment: Super, would you be able to include a link where I can learn about how unpacking works in the context of the question?

Comment: I believe there are many materials on 'python unpacking'. Just like this one: https://towardsdatascience.com/unpacking-operators-in-python-306ae44cd480

Comment: And just for clarity, in the example you've shown you can also use an 'explode' or 'unpacking' operator (*) which makes it even easier, without the need to create another variable:

    s = {'item'}
    print(*s)

Comment: Another good tutorial to explain the concept: https://geekflare.com/python-unpacking-operators/

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `.pop()`. It will return an arbitrary item. If it's empty, you'll have `KeyError: 'pop from an empty set'`

Here's a simple example:

```
test_set = {'word'}
print(test_set.pop() + ' and another word')
```

Comment: pop() modifies the set, which may not be your intention

Comment: True, didn't think about that! I assumed it was a one time use case.

Comment: for just simple printing (or passing to another function) you can use the 'explode' operator (*):
print(*test_set, 'and another word)